# Python MNE: How to read from a .txt file?

Tags: mne-python

I have eeg data in the form of a text file, how do I read it using mne in python?

I converted it into an array, but the data is 1-D, so I don't understand how to proceed further. And then I want to perform welch periodogram on the data, how to do that afterwards?